# Can i use some eclipse libraries in intellij IDE?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I have to use some eclipse libraries (org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3. *), But I would like to continue developing in intellij, can i?

Comment: Sure, that is just a regular lib. See https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.2.5/eclipse-plugin

Comment: Yes. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html on how to add libraries into IntelliJ.

Comment: You can always add them using Maven or Gradle.  The question is: why would you want to?  Hasn't been updated in a year and a half.  You'd be better off finding something that still under active development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

This particular library is hosted by the "Eclipse Foundation", which also hosts the Eclipse IDE. So they share a name, but the Eclipse IDE [is not a dependency](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.2.5/eclipse-plugin).